# Safari blocks URL from asking for credentials because it's a cross-origin request

Tags: ios, safari, webkit, cross-domain

Since iOS 12 Safari blocks my url from asking for credentials because it's a cross-origin request. Everything worked fine with iOS 11. So I think that all headers are set right.

The console output is:

```
Blocked *URL* from asking for credentials because it is a cross-origin request.
```

I can't find anything in the release notes that indicates what may have changed.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safari_release_notes/safari_12_release_notes

Does anybody of you know what Apple changed in Safari 12 to increase the security / block cross-origin requests from asking for credentials?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Webkit disallowes cross-origin subresources from asking for credentials https://trac.webkit.org/changeset/228486/webkit/ but it must be possible to fix this...

Answer (score 9):

Adding `crossorigin` to the script element should fix this issue according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56557082/safari-blocked-https-from-asking-for-credentials-because-it-is-a-cross-o).
Example:

```
<script src="my-code.js" type="module" crossorigin></script>
```

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_settings_attributes