# Safari: "Blocked https://... from asking for credentials because it is a cross-origin request." after updating to Angular 8

Tags: angular, safari, basic-authentication

We have secured our Angular web app with Basic Auth.
After **updating** our app **from Angular 7 to 8.0**, we are no longer asked for the credentials in Safari and the following errors appear in the console:

```
[Error] Blocked https://*/runtime-es2015.4f263ec725bc7710f1f5.js from asking for credentials because it is a cross-origin request.
[Error] Blocked https://*/main-es2015.6fa442dd5c5a204f47da.js from asking for credentials because it is a cross-origin request.
[Error] Blocked https://*/polyfills-es2015.fd951ae1d7572efa3bc6.js from asking for credentials because it is a cross-origin request.
```

In Firefox and Chrome the app still runs without problems. Safari version is 12.1.1.

Does anyone have any idea what the problem with Safari is?

Comment: Just tested and removing basic-auth did 'fix' it, thank you

Comment: Did anyone actually get to the bottom of this issue?

Answer (score 21):

Since angular/cli 8.1 (PR) there is a option **crossOrigin** for the ng build command ([documentation](https://angular.io/cli/build#options)). Possible values are: none | anonymous | use-credentials (defaults to none).

Using this option will alter the script tags in index.html to add the crossorigin attribute.

You can either use this temporary for a build using:
`ng build --crossOrigin=anonymous`

Or use the option in your angular.json under architect.build.options:

```
"architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "crossOrigin": "anonymous", // <-- set value here
        // other options
```

Comment: This should be marked as the answer.   What I would further like to know is why this is a problem with Safari but not the other browsers.

Comment: I tried it both ways and I keep getting an error. In the command line console it says unknown options --crossOrigin and in angular.json it says Schema validation failed with the following errors:
  Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(crossOrigin) any idea why it is not working?

Comment: You should even use `"crossOrigin": "use-credentials"` in some cases (I use a Google OAuth2 authentication).

Answer (score 10):

It seems like some changes of the module scripts spec (https://github.com/whatwg/html/pull/3656) has not been yet implemented in Safari. For me it works on Safari Technology Preview.

In the meantime, you can fix it by adding the `crossorigin` attribute on your module scripts, like this:

```
<script src="runtime-es2015.ff56c41ec157e6d9b0c8.js" type="module" crossorigin></script>
```

---

Here is the solution I have adopted (requires one third party package).

First, install this custom webpack builder: [`@angular-builders/custom-webpack`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-builders/custom-webpack):

```
npm i -D @angular-builders/custom-webpack
```

Be sure to check the prerequisites in its readme and update other dependencies as needed.

Update your `angular.json` to make use of the builder and set the `indexTransform` option:

```
"projects": {
  ...
  "your-app": {
    ...
    "architect": {
      ...
      "build": {
        "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser"
        "options": {
            "indexTransform": "./index-html-transform.js"
              ...
        }
```

Finally, create a file named `index-html-transform.js` in the root directory of your project with the following contents:

```
module.exports = (targetOptions, indexHtml) => {
  const regex = /(<script.*?type="module".*?)>/gim;
  return indexHtml.replace(regex, "$1 crossorigin>");
};
```

Now, when you build your app and the `index.html` is emitted, it will automatically add the `crossorigin` attribute to every module script.

Comment: How can someone go about doing this? Angular adds that tag in by itself (without the crossorigin attribute)

Comment: @MikeFurlender I've updated my answer with the solution I am currently using (I had not find one when I initially answered)

Answer (score 6):

My solution is to add `--subresource-integrity` flag when building:

```
ng build --subresource-integrity
```

This flag also adds `crossorigin` attribute to module scripts according to [this comment](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7301#issuecomment-460674179).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with Angular 8. To fix the issue I just edited my `tsconfig.json` as it was with Angular 7:

```
{
  ...
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "module": "es2015",
    ...
    "target": "es5",
    ...
  }
}
```