# Safari blocks htpasswd protected Angular Files

Tags: angular, apache, safari

I've got a Problem with my apache2 Server and Safari.
I have 2 Angular web apps running on my dev server (Ubuntu 18.04, apache2).

App1 is stored in /var/www/html/app1
App2 is stored in /var/www/html/app2

In /var/www/html I have an index.html with "Dev Server Running" showing and an .htacces file with the Headers no-index rule.

In App1 and App2 I have exactly the same .htaccess .htpasswd files (except the paths to redirect and the htpasswd).

When I open /app1 everything works fine in all Browser.

When I open /app2 in Safari I got the following error:

Blocked XXX/runtime-es2015.xxx.js from asking for credentials because it is a cross-origin request.

This message shows up for every js file.
If I open the same URL with Chrome everything works.

App1 was created with Angular 6 I guess and App2 with Angular 8.
App1 is now rebuild with angular-cli 8 and should have run the same building process.

Can anyone help me with that?

I've tried:
- Reinstalling apache
- new subfolders

.htacces:

```
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow"

AuthName "XXX"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile "/var/www/html/app2/.htpasswd
require valid-user

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*) /app2/index.html [NC,L]
```

If I remove "require valid-user", safari works.

Comment: Did you maybe find a solution yet?

Comment: I'm afraid not. I gave it up :D

Comment: A pity!
Thanks for your reply!

Comment: I think it's related to this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56557082/safari-blocked-https-from-asking-for-credentials-because-it-is-a-cross-o

You will also find a solution there